# Factory with generic protocol swift

Tags: swift

I am creating a **generic parser** in my Network Layer with the help of **associatedType** and a **Factory**. Basic purpose is that I will call only one static function to whom I will pass type and data. It will do all the parsing stuff and will return me a Parsed Model Object.

```
protocol Parsable: Codable {
    associatedtype JSON
    static func Parse(object: Data) -> JSON?
}
```

> Creation of Factory

```
struct ParseFactory<object: Parsable> {

    let type: RequestType

    func doParsing(data: Data) -> object.JSON? {

      switch type {

        case .RequestOne:
        return ModelOne.Parse(object: data) as? object.JSON

        case .RequestTwo:
        return ModelTwo.Parse(object: data) as? object.JSON
    }
  }
}
```

> Model Objects that create their own parsing stuff

```
class ModelOne: Parsable {

       typealias JSON = ModelOne
       let name: String

    static func Parse(object: Data) -> JSON? {
       let photoObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ModelOne.self, from: object)
       return photoObject
    }
}

class ModelTwo: Parsable {

       typealias JSON = ModelTwo
       let name: String

    static func Parse(object: Data) -> JSON? {
      let photoObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ModelTwo.self, from: object)
      return photoObject
   }
}
```

> Call from Network Layer with single Line

```
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // parsing
        if let dataNotNil = data {
         //   _ = Parsable
        }
    }
```

> Question: How can I call the one line factory function that will call the respective function of Model.

Note: Any Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can use

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"yoururl")!)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let dataNotNil = data {
        let objectParse = ParseFactory<ModelOne>(type: RequestType.RequestOne)
        let modelOneObjc  = objectParse.doParsing(data: dataNotNil)
        print(modelOneObjc?.name)
    }
}
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: I want to do the parsing only on the request type that is why I have made a factory for that purpose and ParseFactory<ModelOne> does not make sense.